# How do you do multiple substrings for a field in Teradata?

Tags: sql, substring, teradata

I have a field to pull account numbers which have different lengths and I want to pass the last four digits of the account number. The dilemma I am having is that since they are different lengths I am having trouble in substringing the fields. The standard length is 11 digits but there are accounts with 9 digits and 7 digits.

How do I substring those values in multiple substrings to capture all the account last 4 digits in one query?

This currently what I have:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(ACCT_NBR,7,4) AS BNK_ACCT_NBR
FROM NAMEOFTABLE;
```

I want to have additional substrings to capture the account numbers that don't have 11 digits similar to

```
SUBSTRING(ACCT_NBR,5,4)
SUBSTRING(ACCT_NBR,4,4)
```

The results should look like:

76587990891 - 0891
654378908   - 8908
45643456    - 3456

Can you please help me in figuring out how I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Here is a sample of what I am looking for:

Acct Number Desired Results
6117969637 9637
5221672389 2389
61004323 4323
7018417         8417
701841         1841

Answer (score 0):

Is ACCT_NBR a VarChar or an INT?

```
VarChar:
Right (ACCT_NBR,4)
Substr(ACCT_NBR,Char_Length(x)-3)

INT:
ACCT_NBR MOD 10000
```

Comment: ACCT_NBR is a VARCHAR field and a total length of 19 characters. I am trying to capture the last four digits in the field. There are multiple entries where the length of the account number is 11 characters, 9 characters and 7 characters. I want to get all of those which are not captured with what I have currently which is:

SUBSTRING(ACCT_NBR,7,4) AS BNK_LST_4_NBR

Comment: The RIGHT(ACCT_NBT,4) command worked for me. Thank you for your help :).